# Accessing the value of sibling element where the values are rendered through JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

The values are placed through JS and I am stuck on this. I was trying to access the value of the `.id` element but to no avail. How do I retrieve the value?

```
<tr class="tablerow">
  <td class="delete"> </td>
  <td class="id"></td>
</tr>

// click function 
$('.delete').click(() =>{

    let id = $(this).next();
    console.log(id) 
    // output rn: 
       test.js:134 
       jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
       length: 0
       prevObject: jQuery.fn.init [Window]
       __proto__: Object(0)
    // tried using .val() .find() .siblings()

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

You can use normal function syntax:

```js
// click function 
$('.delete').click(function() {
  let id = $(this).next('.id').text();
  console.log(id);
})
```

```css
.delete{background-color: lightgray}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class="tablerow">
      <td class="delete"> Delete </td>
      <td class="id">Some Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablerow">
      <td class="delete"> Delete </td>
      <td class="id">Some Text2</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

You can still use arrow function by passing the `event` to the function so that you can use `target` property to refer the current element:

```js
// click function 
$('.delete').click((e) => {
  let id = $(e.target).next('.id').text();
  console.log(id);
})
```

```css
.delete{background-color: lightgray}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="tablerow">
      <td class="delete"> Delete </td>
      <td class="id">Some Text</td>
  </tr>    
  <tr class="tablerow">
      <td class="delete"> Delete </td>
      <td class="id">Some Text2</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Good catch! Typical case of skipping the basics.

Comment: @kathmandu, your comment is not clear...may be you can update the question by producing the problem....thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```js
$('.delete').click(function(){

    let id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.id').text();
    console.log(id) 
 

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="tablerow">
            <td class="delete"> delete</td>
            <td class="id">1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tablerow">
            <td class="delete">delete</td>
            <td class="id">2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tablerow">
            <td class="delete">delete </td>
            <td class="id">3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to access table cell with class `id`. You can do it like this

```
$('.delete').click(() =>{
    let id = $(this).closest('td');
})
```